# Pulling Most Frequent Combination from csv columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I been trying to pull the most frequent combination for Start and End station from the csv file, the problem I am having is I am pulling all of them. When trying to pull just the one most combined, I just get a number?

```
def station_stats(df):

frequent_stations = df.groupby(['Start Station'])['End Station'].value_counts().mode
print('Most frequent start and end station: ', frequent_stations)
```

Below is snippet of what I am currently outputting:

```
Most frequent start and end station:  <bound method Series.mode of Start Station                 End Station

2112 W Peterson Ave           Warren Park East                    8
                          Clark St & Berwyn Ave               5
                          Washtenaw Ave & Lawrence Ave        4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.groupby(['Start Station','End Station']).size().nlargest(1)
```

Comment: Thank you that definitely helped.

Comment: @WalterSolares if this is what you need would you like accept it?

Comment: Accept it? Yeah, that seemed to have worked for me. The nlargest was the missing piece I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @WalterSolares I mean the check mark in the left of my answer :-)